# Wikipedia API Hello World not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

The following simple code isn't working for Wikipedia API. I'm not sure why.

html:

```
<button id="main" onclick=doThis()>Main</button>
<div id="result">h<div>
```

Script:

```
function doThis() {
var wikiUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json";
$.getJSON(wikiUrl, function(data) {
  alert(data);
}, 
  $('#result').html("no")
)}
```

Output:
the `$('#result').html("no")` line gets executed which I believe means that the getJSON didn't return anything.

What's wrong & how do I fix this?

Comment: Your `$('#result').html("no")` will just execute that code fragment right away, it is not a callback.

Comment: I added that in to see if anything at all was working. Without that the app feels like a brick. But the thing is- why isn't the JSON getting fetched?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't? Have you checked the web console to see what happens to the ajax call?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the browser's console, you'll see this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access.

This indicates that you need to instruct `$.getJSON()` to use `jsonp`.

To do so, simply add

```
&callback=?
```

to your url.

But, as @Rory commented, note:

Note that JSON and JSONP aren't directly interchangeable. This only works here as Wikipedia supports JSONP, whereas many API providers do not.

So changing your code to

```
function doThis() {

    var wikiUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&callback=?";

    $.getJSON(wikiUrl, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }); 
)}
```

will work.

Note that `$('#result').html("no")` is not a callback, so using it as one doesn't have any positive effect.

Comment: Good answer, although note that JSON and JSONP aren't directly interchangeable. This only works here as Wikipedia supports JSONP, whereas many API providers do not.

Comment: well its working now. But I didn't really get the issue. Does wikipedia only provide jsonp or it does json as well?

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan I added that to the answer!

Comment: You need to use jsonp for front-end cross domain requests without cors headers, as it bypasses restrictions of browsers' same-origin policy . @DrConfuse . Read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 1):

You have some CORS issue on the call, besides your error callback is wrong.

Try with

```
$.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&callback=?', function(data) {
   alert(data);
}, function() {
  $('#result').html("no");
});
```